# How to compare dataframe columns using a given value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame( {'InLevel_03': [12, 12, 13, 12, 11,], 'InLevel_02': [11.5, 11.5, 12.5, 11.5, 10.5], 'InLevel_01': [11, 10.5, 12, 10.5, 9], 'OutLevel_01': [10.5, 10, 11.5, 10, 8.5], 'OutLevel_02': [10, 9.5, 11, 9.5, 8], 'OutLevel_03': [9.5, 9, 10, 9, 7.5]} )

>>> df
   InLevel_03  InLevel_02  InLevel_01  OutLevel_01  OutLevel_02  OutLevel_03
0          12        11.5        11.0         10.5         10.0          9.5
1          12        11.5        10.5         10.0          9.5          9.0
2          13        12.5        12.0         11.5         11.0         10.0
3          12        11.5        10.5         10.0          9.5          9.0
4          11        10.5         9.0          8.5          8.0          7.5
```

If the given value is `0.5`, I want to check if there's a gap bigger than the given value in a row. For example, in the 2nd row, there's a gap between InLevel_02(11.5) and InLevel_01(10.5), which is 11. In the 5th row, the gaps are 10 and 9.5, between InLevel_02(10.5) and InLevel_01(9.0).

The result of this job would look like this:

```
 gapLevel    count    # row number, column name of each gap
       11        2    # (1, InLevel_02 - 1, InLevel_01), (3, InLevel_02 - 3, InLevel_01)
     10.5        1    # (2, OutLevel_02 - 2, OutLevel_03)
       10        1    # (4, InLevel_02 - 4, InLevel_01)
      9.5        1    # (4, InLevel_02 - 4, InLevel_01)
```

I tried converting the dataframe into an array(using .to_records) and comparing each value with its next value using loops, but the code gets too complicated when there are more than 1 level between two values and I'd like to know if there are more efficient ways to do this.

Comment: understood what needs to be done...but can you just explain more about your output df? how is `gapLevel` matching with values in input `df`?

Comment: Also do you want only these two columns in your output df i.e. `gapLevel` and `count`. You don't want to merge these columns in orginial `df'

Comment: @Rahul Agarwal Thank you for the reply. I added how the result was made. I just counted missing gaps per level in the original dataframe. I think the result should be done in a new dataframe due to its different shape.

Comment: So the gaps are between values within a row, are the gaps between any paid of values within that row or only pairs which sit next to each other?

Comment: @cardamom I'm sorry for the lack of clearness of my question. I mean pairs which sit next to each other. You can see that levels in the first row decrease by 0.5 ```(12, 11.5, 11.0, 10.5 , 10.0 , 9.5).``` If it's not by 0.5 but 1(1 gap exists) or 1.5(2 gaps exist), it's not continuous and there's a gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

You can begin by obtaining a list of indices of rows and columns from which to extract the counts checking where the `df` minus a shifted version of itself (see [`pd.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)) is greater than `0.5`:

```
t = 0.5
# df = df.astype(float) # if it isn't already
rows, cols = np.where(df - df.shift(-1, axis = 1) > t)
# (array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([1, 4, 1, 1]))
```

Get the arange from the values in these rows and columns using a list comprehension as (note that this approach assumes that the values keep decreasing throughout the columns):

```
v = [np.arange(*df.iloc[r,[c+1, c]].values, step=t)[1:] for r, c in zip(rows, cols)]
# [array([11.]), array([10.5]), array([11.]), array([ 9.5, 10. ])]
```

Create a new `Series` from the counts using `Counter`:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

x = list(chain.from_iterable(v.values))
#[11.0, 10.5, 11.0, 9.5, 10.0]
pd.Series(Counter(x), name = 'count')

11.0    2
10.5    1
9.5     1
10.0    1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It works fine and I've learned some new ways to manipulate data thnaks to you. However, it takes minutes to do ```[np.arange(*df.iloc[r,[c+1, c]].values, step=t)[1:] for r, c in zip(rows, cols)]``` job with my ```(610178, 10)``` shaped dataframe. Could there be a more efficient way to do this?